# How to set detectHandlerMethodsInAncestorContexts true?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller

In spring-webmvc, there is a param `detectHandlerMethodsInAncestorContexts` in [AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.html).

Its default value is false. How can I set it true?

Comment: Is there anybody can help me?

Comment: The question is that I want to add to @Controller to webmvc's parent context(builed by ContextLoaderListener),but I found that there is a filed named detectHandlerMethodsInAncestorContexts in AbstractHandlerMethodMapping(Spring-webmvc's source),only when the boolean is true,springmvc while deal the parent context's controller,but I can't find where to set it true.

Comment: Improved grammar, formatting and linked to the Spring docs.

Comment: Please consider sharing your code so that we are able to see the context of where you are trying to set this to true.

Answer (score 0):

Just create the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` bean explicitly and set this value to `true`

```
@Bean
public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
    RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping = new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
    requestMappingHandlerMapping.setDetectHandlerMethodsInAncestorContexts(true);
    return requestMappingHandlerMapping;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Spring 4 (Boot 1.5) this worked for me:

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.app")
class WebpageContext extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    protected RequestMappingHandlerMapping createRequestMappingHandlerMapping() {
       RequestMappingHandlerMapping mapping = new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
       mapping.setDetectHandlerMethodsInAncestorContexts(true); 
       return mapping;
    }
}
```

(Normally you annotate your `@Configuration` class with `@EnableWebMvc` and extend `@WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` but it does not expose the request mapping so we need to extend `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` directly.)